# Can the code in django be made to read by the javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

what happens is that I already have the behavior to add rows (JS and HTML) with my plus sign, however I have the problem that the form that is duplicated (with the formset) does not have the code in django, and obviously what I want is that I add the rows with the HTML, JS and Django.

**I wish I could recycle my code so that cell1.outerHTML (and the others) could contain something like this: {% render_field form.code class = "form-control"%}**

I just don't know if it can be done, hopefully because my knowledge of JS is minimal :(

> presupuestos-forms.html

```
                                                                  <table class="table table-bordered table-nowrap align-middle" id="childTable1">
                                                                               <thead class="table-info">
                                                                                 <tr>
                                                                                   <th scope="col">Código</th>
                                                                                   <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                                                                                   <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                                                                                   <th scope="col">Precio Unitario</th>
                                                                                   <th scope="col">Precio Total</th>
                                                                                   <th scope="col">Libre de Impuestos</th>
                                                                                   <th scope="col">Agrega Fila</th>
                                                                                 </tr>
                                                                               </thead>
                                                                               <tbody>
                                                                                 <tr>
                                                                                   <td>
                                                                                       {{presupuestosparteform.codigo}}
                                                                                   </td>
                                                                                   <td>
                                                                                     {{presupuestosparteform.descripcion}}
                                                                                   </td>
                                                                                   <td>
                                                                                     {{presupuestosparteform.quantity}}
                                                                                   </td>
                                                                                   <td>
                                                                                     {{presupuestosparteform.unit_price}}
                                                                                   </td>
                                                                                   <td>
                                                                                     {{presupuestosparteform.total_price}}
                                                                                   </td>
                                                                                   <td>
                                                                                       <div>
                                                                                           {{presupuestosparteform.tax_free}}
                                                                                       </div>
                                                                                   </td>
                                                                                   <td>
                                                                                     <input type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" id="addrow" onclick="childrenRow()" value="+" />
                                                                                   </td>

                                                                                 </tr>
                                                                                   <tr>
                                                                                   {{ formset.management_form }}
                                                                                   {% for form in formset %}
                                                                                       <td>
                                                                                           {% render_field form.codigo class="form-control" %}
                                                                                       </td>
                                                                                       <td>
                                                                                           {% render_field form.descripcion class="form-control" %}
                                                                                       </td>
                                                                                       <td>
                                                                                           {% render_field form.quantity class="form-control" %}
                                                                                       </td>
                                                                                       <td>
                                                                                           {% render_field form.unit_price class="form-control" %}
                                                                                       </td>
                                                                                       <td>
                                                                                           {% render_field form.total_price class="form-control" %}
                                                                                       </td>
                                                                                       <td>
                                                                                           {% render_field form.tax_free class="form-check-input" %}
                                                                                       </td>

                                                                                   {% endfor %}
                                                                                   </tr>
                                                                               </tbody>
                                                                             </table>
```

> add-parts-rows.js

```
            function deleteRow(id)
            {
            document.getElementById(id).remove()
            }

            function childrenRow() {

            var table = document.getElementById("childTable1");
            // GET TOTAL NUMBER OF ROWS
            var x =table.rows.length;
            var id = "tbl"+x;
            var row = table.insertRow(x);
            row.id=id;
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            cell1.outerHTML = ' <td><input type="text" name="parts_code" class="form-control input-new-customer-code newcode" autofocus/></td>';
            cell2.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" name="parts_description" class="form-control input-new-customer-description" />';
            cell3.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" name="parts_quantity" class="form-control input-new-customer-quantity" />';
            cell4.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" name="parts_unit_price" class="form-control input-new-customer-unit-price" />';
            cell5.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" name="parts_total_price" class="form-control input-new-customer-total" />';
            cell6.innerHTML = '  <input type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" id="addrow" onclick="deleteRow(\''+id+'\')" value="Delete" /> ';
            }
            document.getElementsByClassName("newcode").onfocus = function() {setFocusInput()};
            function setFocusInput(){
                document.getElementsByClassName("newcode").focus();
            }
```